# Avoiding lot of roles implementation in same object

Tags: java, object-oriented

### Motivation

Let a project where...

... exists a lot different behaviors. For each behavior, there is an interface which has its possible actions. One object could perform a lot different behaviors.

Normally, a collaborator "A" only cares about interface "I" from a specific object.

So, how to avoid a object to implements lot of roles.

Example:

```
public class MyComplexObject implements Closeable, Reliable, Trustable, Treable, Moveable { ...}
```

### Why bother?

Composition solves the problem. But only partially. In Java, the target object will still have to delegate the problem calls for the target implementation. Although it is no-brain implementation, it is not comfortable when the list of roles is more than 5.

Inheritance (over interfaces) will not turn things better.

Let's assume 6 different interfaces (each interface with 5 methods). For now, let us simplify and imagine a default implementation for those interfaces. Now, assume that a set of more complex objects could implement one to six of those interfaces. It means 2^6= 64 different possible combinations. Also, long list of interface means a long list of internal methods.

It is clear that inheritance, using a BaseImplementation, does not make sense in this case.

Examples:

```
public class MyComplexObject1 implements Closeable, Reliable, Trustable, Treable, Moveable { ...}
public class MyComplexObject2 implements Reliable, Treable, Moveable { ...}
public class MyComplexObject3 implements Reliable, Trustable, Moveable { ...}
public class MyComplexObject4 implements Closeable, Trustable, Treable { ...}
```

### I am not asking for a silver bullet

"Being skeptical", "avoiding complexity" of course, those thing are good. However, too general. This problem is when long list of roles hurts. So this is a corner case scenario and not a mainstream problem.

What does not mean unrealistic scenario. There is a project that use an idea that could be used to solve that problem.

Netbeans, that has the concept of cookies

```
EditorCookie ec = activatedNodes[0].getLookup().lookup(EditorCookie.class);
```

> A cookie is a capability and cookies are a powerful feature of NetBeans. With a Java interface, your object's capabilities are fixed at compile time, while NetBeans cookies allow your object to behave dynamically because your object can expose capabilities, or not, based on its state.

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-porting-basic.html

#### How cookies-like could be implemented

```
public class MyComplexObject { 
    private Map<Class<?>, ?> adapters;

    public <T> T getAdapterIfApplicable(Class<T> t){
       return (T) adapters.get(t);
    }
    public MyComplexObject add(Class<T> aClass, T t){
       adapters(aClass, t);
       t.setTarget(this);
    }
...
}
...
public CloseableAdapter implements Adapter{
    void setTarget(Object target){
        this.target = target; 
    }
}
...
new MyComplexObject().add(CloseableAdapter.class, aCloseAdapter);
```

Comment: How do you propose having a typesafe collection of Closeable objects?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean about Closeable objects? The propose (it was not mine) is to have a typesafe way to get an object that perform a behavior (it should be the adapter, that somehow could for example delegate some action to the target object internally)

Comment: By not having `public class Foo implements Bar, Qux, Baz` you can't put an object of Foo in a `Collection<Bar>`. Is this a problem for you?

Comment: ooo sorry... for list I mean a list of declared intefaces. In your example... Bar, Qux, Baz.

Comment: What do you mean by "adapter for that interface"? A helper class which holds an instance of `MyComplexObject` and implements the desired interface, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Object_Adapter_pattern? If so, how are you going to specify the adapter type in `getAdapterIfAppliable`? And how will you distinguish between different adapters if there is more than one that fits?

Comment: please, check the new code.

Comment: This approach allows you to configure the available adapters for each instance of `MyComplexObject` individually. Is that flexibility really what you *need*? Seems it will come for the cost of a lot of additional overhead, in code to maintain, in memory for each object, and maybe in running time. If you do not need really the flexibility, you are at risk of overengineering things.

Comment: Imagine that MyComplexObject is just one example from a set (maybe 30 different objects each one implementing a specific combination of interfaces). So, of course, it is not a general solution my applicable in some cases, as far as I understood.

Comment: *... how to avoid a object to implements a long list of interfaces. ...* Why do you see this as a problem?

Comment: It's Java, it's supposed to be obscenely verbose.

Comment: @rdllopes: please address people with "@ name", otherwise we do not see your answers in our inbox. You did not answer my question - do you need that flexibility really on a **per instance** level? All you write is you need that flexibility on a "per class" level (when you write 30 different objects, you mean 30 different classes, I guess?)

Comment: @DocBrown, I don't need the flexibility per instance level. I can write multiples classes and achieve that "flexibility". 
I added more info in my question to clarify those points.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, yes I see. =)  I added more info in my question to clarify those points.

Comment: @rdllopes - I still do not see **why this is a problem**. I think you are seeing a problem that only exists to you. I have worked on hundreds of millions of lines of Java code since 1995. I have never seen the *problem* you seem to be concerned about.

Comment: @rdllopes - your question is an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where `Y` is this *Adapter Pattern* solution and you are asking if it is a good design, when you need to be asking what others have done, it is not this *Adapter Pattern* approach.

Answer (score 9):

It appears from the comments and edits that your concern is more about duplicating code in multiple implementation classes. That has **nothing** to do with how many interfaces are implemented.

#### Composite Pattern with Delegation

If the implementations of each interface is generic then they should be classes that are delegated to using the `Composite` Pattern. The adapter pattern is not the solution either way.

If `A implements C` then `A` **is a** `C`. To burden the calling code with this obfuscation of `Adapter` Pattern is a terrible API decision.

#### The question you are asking is not the correct one:

*... how to avoid a object to implements a long list of interfaces.*

I think you are seeing a problem that only exists to you. I have worked on hundreds of millions of lines of Java code since 1995. I have never seen the *problem* you seem to be concerned about.

The number of combinations of interfaces is not a practical issue. Never has been. If you have too many interfaces with to many methods then that is a design problem that needs to be fixed, your *solution* is not that *fix*.

#### You are adding a ridiculous amount of complexity for no apparent benefit:

`implements` means what is implementing that interface **is a** relationship, that is pretty tightly coupled and introducing `Adapter` pattern type indirection is going to bloat the codebase with more complexity and code to maintain and test, which is a good enough reason to not do that.

If this was a good approach it would have been done half a dozen times as an opensource library the 20 years that Java has been around.

This *Adapter Pattern* you are trying to use is not the correct approach, it will create a heavy burdensome API and be extremely brittle.

The work to **use** the API will be orders of magnitude more effort than maintaining naively duplicated code.